# Are there any webcam programs that save the date in the meta data?

Tags: webcam, shotwell, cheese

I currently use Cheese, but it isn't really compatible with Shotwell because it doesn't save the date in the meta data - only the file name.

I could run a command to get the file name and put it into the meta data, but I wonder if there is another webcam utility that will save the date in the meta data automatically, or if there is a way for cheese to do so.

UPDATE - newer photos taken with cheese seem to. Maybe a backup / resore issue. I'd still be interested in others that do save it.

Answer (score 1):

Guvcview should do it. It has pretty good EXIF metadata support (and EXIF Date is the most basic one anyway). Just checked a capture and dates are definitely saved in METADATA.

You could try mencoder / VLC for other webcam capture options.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could compose image filenames before they are created, and incorporate functional metadata that will enable the creation of new images at 1/sec; which can then be used as the moniker employed to save the image(s) in the filesystem:
   datefn=`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%I-%M-%S"`; savefn="$datefn-Cheese-img"; echo $savefn